# Theming inside blocks

Tags: blocks, theming

I don't know the process to theme inside regions in Drupal 8. I have the knowledge to theme regions by putting {{ page.XXX }} in the twig file (with regions declaration in the YML file) .But for example I have the "Content" region containing 2 blocks: Page Title and Main Page Content. How can I do to theme only the Page Title or the Main Page Content block in the twig file, also with the fields inside the blocks (text, title and such). Any help is most appreciated.